Chrome picking wrong srcset image at random breakpoint
Given the following snippet:


<html>
  <body>
    <img
      srcset="
        https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0277/6992/9843/files/anti-aging-face-cream---normal-_-comb.-skin-both_400x.png?v=1709808291   400w,
        https://steemitimages.com/1280x0/http://cnnphilippines.com/incoming/zgzt53-aliens.jpg/ALTERNATES/FREE_720/aliens.jpg            800w,
        https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0277/6992/9843/files/anti-aging-face-cream---normal-_-comb.-skin-both_1200x.png?v=1709808291 1200w
      "
      sizes="282px"
    />
  </body>
</html>



The browser loads the _400x.png image, which is the expected result.
However, when I turn sizes="282px" into sizes="283px", the browser inexplicably switches to the 800w image (which I've turned into a different image to more clearly illustrate):


<html>
  <body>
    <img
      srcset="
        https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0277/6992/9843/files/anti-aging-face-cream---normal-_-comb.-skin-both_400x.png?v=1709808291   400w,
        https://steemitimages.com/1280x0/http://cnnphilippines.com/incoming/zgzt53-aliens.jpg/ALTERNATES/FREE_720/aliens.jpg            800w,
        https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0277/6992/9843/files/anti-aging-face-cream---normal-_-comb.-skin-both_1200x.png?v=1709808291 1200w
      "
      sizes="283px"
    />
  </body>
</html>



What is happening here?

sizes="(max-width: 400px) 400px, (max-width: 800px) 800px, 1200px"?

@imhvost try it out, it doesn't work. In another test I did it loaded a 828px under 400 with this sizes property, and over 400 it switched to 1200px. It never showed the 800px. I can only assume there is some very weird internal browser heuristics powering this selection.
